# Collapsing a Menu with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a JQuery menu that needs to expand and collapse. However, I'm having some issues getting the sub-menus to line up like I would like. Basically, I want the sub menu items to be in-line with the top-menu items. However, as it stands now, the entire sub-menu item is indented. My code looks like the following:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="theMenu"> 
  <li><a title="open or close this section" href="#">Info</a>                    
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">Basic</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Advanced</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </li> 

  <li><a title="open or close this section" href="#">Documents</a> 
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">Newsletters</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Policies and Procedures</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">job Descriptions</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </li> 
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#theMenu > li > a").not(":first").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);
  $("#theMenu > li > a").click(function () {
    $(this).find("+ ul").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#theMenu, #theMenu ul { list-style:none; width:15em; }
#theMenu a { background:#F6F6F6; color:#010101; 
  display:block; font-weight:bold; padding:0.5em 1em; text-decoration:none; 
  border:1px solid #DFDFDF; 
}
#theMenu ul a { background:#F6F6F6; color:#010101; 
  font-weight:normal; text-decoration:none; 
}
#theMenu ul a:hover { background:#F0EBE1; text-decoration:underline; color:#711515; }
```

How do I make the sub menus flush with the left edge of the root menu?

Thank you!

ADDED: Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jM99n/)

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/brianflanagan/sH2WJ/  What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#theMenu, #theMenu ul { list-style:none; width:15em; }
```

on

```
#theMenu, #theMenu ul { list-style:none; width:15em;margin:0;padding:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok on FF what's the browser you are using?